# Why file upload fails in asp.net fileupload control?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, webforms, image-uploading

Why Upload fails at `if(FileUpload1.HasFile)`, it returns false. even it has image but still returns false. WHY ?

```
protected void btnUploadFard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
               

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/DataManagement/FardImages/") + fileName);
               
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
        finally { }
    }
}
```

see after browsing and selecting image, it shows name next to it.
[image]

but when I click Upload then it shows this

[image]

and in debugging it shows false for `Fileupload1.HasFile`

Comment: `FileUpload1` is it your FileUpload Control ID?? or you missed something??
update question and add some `.aspx` page code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">` for the `<input type="file" />` input to work in web-forms. The implicit default (`enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`) does not support file uploads.

Without setting this correctly, ASP.NET will not be able to read uploaded files so the `.HasFile` property will be false.

Comment: but form is in master page and i also tried ur solution in master page but didn't work